# Intermittent windows sign-in pop up in ASP .NET MVC 5.2.0 hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication, windows-server-2019

I have an ASP.NET MVC application hosted on IIS on windows server 2019. The webapp runs fine but upon clicking a button(which triggers a service call), I get windows sign-in pop up intermittently.

[image]

Note that, we have disabled windows authentication at IIS level and user authentication is being done at application level using Azure active directory.

[image]

We have the following authentication settings in web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="None" />
   <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
     ...
</modules>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis First you need to know what error code 401.x was returned by IIS.

Comment: May be the case: If the authenticated user is not able to read the folders for static content in your web application, it will authenticate it, you can try to grant `local_Machine\Authenicated_Users` access to the the `IIS_IUSRS` group.

Comment: Hit F12 and view the network traffic to see the exact error code and which URL caused it.